# Is Dedekind completion of ${}^{\ast}\Bbb R$ a Archimedean field?

Tags: nonstandard-analysis

Here's Theorem 1.2 on page 6, Martin Andreas Väth's Nonstandard Analysis(See [here](http://books.google.com.hk/books?hl=zh-CN&id=sxxFDijkS1UC&q=theorem+1.2#v=snippet&q=theorem%201.2&f=false) on googlebooks)

> The Dedekind completion $\overline{X}$ of a totally ordered field $X$
>   is a complete Archimedean field with $\Bbb{Q}_{\overline{X}}$ as the canonical copy of $\Bbb{Q}_{X}$.

$X$ has the Archimedean property. For each $x \in X$ there is some $n \in \Bbb{N}_{X}$
such that $n > x$.
Each totally ordered field X contains a “canonical copy” of the set $\Bbb{N}_{X}$, namely $\{1_X, 1_X +1_X, 1_X +1_X +1_X, \ldots\}$.

${}^{\ast}\Bbb R$ is a totally ordered field without Archimedean property. Isn't it the case that its Dedekind completion doesn't have Archimedean property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Dedekind-completion is an order completion, and if the field is non-Arcihmedean then its Dedekind-completion is not a field at all.

To see this simply note that in the completion, there is a point $t$ which is the realization of the cut $R=\{x\mid\exists n\in\Bbb N. x<n\}$. And $t-1$ cannot exist.

Comment: Thank you! So there's something wrong with the phrasing of the theorem. $X$ must be an Arcihmedean totally ordered field. Another question: Perhaps I misunderstand you, do you mean $t^{-1}$?

Comment: Yes, that does seem like a mistake in the phrasing. About the second question, either one, really. If $t-1$ exists then it has to be smaller than some $n\in\Bbb N$, and then so does $t$. Similar arguments can be made about $t^{-1}$ too.